# selenium chrome tabcapture Requested device not found

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to use chrome's tabCapture api to capture audio in a selenium instance and keep running into "Requested device not found".

Here is an example chrome extension background script

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  console.log("browserAction")
  chrome.tabCapture.capture(
    {video: false, audio: true},
    function(stream) {
      if (!stream) {
        console.error('Error starting tab capture: ' +
                      (chrome.runtime.lastError.message || 'UNKNOWN'));
        return;
      }
      console.log("got stream")
    }
  );
});
```

Using this background script in a regular chrome instance works as expected but if I start selenium and manually click the browserAction button the chrome runtime error "Requested device was not found" is logged in the background console.

I have tried selenium with and without --use-fake-device-for-media-stream and --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream.

Just in case this seem rather pointless the reason I am doing this I have a larger extension that I use during my tests and some tests need to record audio and or video. I would perfer to not have to record it at the system level if possible so I was trying to use tabCapture. I can get around a user action being required to activate the tabCapture by white listing my extension.

Any possible solutions would be absolutely great. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out?

Comment: No I did not. In my specific case I really only needed to record audio/video coming from a webrtc stream and ended up using the solution I posted here for that purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170060/ways-to-capture-incoming-webrtc-video-streams-client-side/49021805#49021805

Comment: The only way I know of to record the audio/video is at the system level using ffserver, Xvfb, and pulse audio. This is extremely taxing on the server when running several tests though.

Comment: I've been trying to take the following approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725650/requested-device-not-found-when-using-chrome-tabcapture-capture?noredirect=1#comment94305702_53725650 - but to no avail.

Comment: Where does the audio come from? Is it a webrtc source? If so see my first reply.

Comment: It could be a WebRTC source but I want to capture any audio coming out of tab. That's why I was thinking chrome.tabCapture is the best approach.

Comment: That is what I initially wanted to do too but wasn't able to get this working after wasting an extreme amount of time on it. Like I said the only way I know for sure is to do it at the system level using ffserver, pulse audio, and xfvb. Each running test would need its own user account and pulse audio config

Comment: Basically what I did to capture all audio was setup each running test case with its own user account, had pulse audio stream the audio to ffserver, and then was able to access all audio in the browser. This is pretty hard on the system when running several test cases on one server.

Comment: See the following for how to set this up in docker https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/147#issuecomment-294318491

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Helpful! When you say "user account", what exactly do you mean?Is it your application's user? System user? Some other user?

Comment: each running test instance where you need to record audio would need its own system user account. this is because without doing that you'll have audio from other test cases bleeding into each other.

Comment: I see, yes, makes sense. I'm thinking of running each instance in a separate Docker container so that should be fine. I'm actually using this to record video conferences, so, fewer instances than if I was running tests.

Comment: I would recommend using the solution that I linked to at first regarding webrtc streams. You would get better quality audio/video and it would be much less taxing on the system. Either way running a seperate docker instance for each conference would work too.

Comment: By the way, on a separate note, how did you "I can get around a user action being required to activate the tabCapture by white listing my extension.". I'm struggling to find any information on that. All resources say the extension has to be invoked first.

Comment: by using the command line option --whitelisted-extension-id

Comment: to expand on that. If you have an extension that is unpacked/unpublished you can simply copy the "key" from another extension's manifest and add that to your unpacked extension's manifest. It will then have the same id as the packed/published extension. otherwise the id will change each time you run an instance

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks.