# "Requested device not found" when using chrome.tabCapture.capture

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

## Problem

I want to capture the audio output of a tab automatically. I'm currently thinking of doing this using Puppeteer (headful), by loading an extension that uses `chrome.tabCapture.capture`. From my Puppeteer script, I evaluate code within the extensions `background.js` to get the tab capture started. However, `chrome.runtime.lastError.message` is set to `Requested device not found`.

The extension works as expected outside of Puppeteer and in a Chrome browser.

Any idea why I'm getting `Requested device not found`?

## What does the extension's `background.js` look like?

```
function startRecording() {
    chrome.tabCapture.capture(options, stream => {
        if (stream === null) {
            console.log(`Last Error: ${chrome.runtime.lastError.message}`);
            return;
        }
        try {
            const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
        recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
            const { data: blob, timecode } = event;
            console.log(`${timecode}: ${blob}`);
        });
        const timeslice = 60 * 1000;
        recorder.start(timeslice);
    });
}
```

## What does the relevant part of your Puppeteer script look like?

```
...

const targets = await browser.targets();
const backgroundPageTarget = targets.find(target => target.type() === 'background_page' && target.url().startsWith('chrome-extension://abcde/'));
const backgroundPage = await backgroundPageTarget.page();

const test = await backgroundPage.evaluate(() => {
    startRecording();
    return Promise.resolve(42);
});

...
```

## Extension Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "test.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "all_frames": false,
            "js": [
                "contentScript.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "tabCapture",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I didn't use this API so without an MCVE I can only guess the [requirements](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture#method-capture) weren't met.

Comment: Could you add the extension manifest?

Comment: I've done that now, @Xan.