# Detect audio on Google Meet with Chrome Extension/Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, google-meet

I'm working on a Google Chrome extensions that automatically mutes the microphone when somebody else is talking, to prevent speaking over each other.

I've started by looking at the Chrome tabs API and I can successfully detect a sound played on a tab through the `onUpdate` event and the `audible` property:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   // Does stuff on changeInfo.audible changed
});
```

The problem is that this event does not fire on audio received from a tab with Google Meet. I'm assuming it's because the audio comes from WebRTC and so it's managed differently.

So I've tried this solution which proxies the WebRTC stream: [Ways to capture incoming WebRTC video streams (client side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170060/ways-to-capture-incoming-webrtc-video-streams-client-side)

The problem is that in this case it looks like the RTCPeerConnection is not built using my proxy.

Is there any way I can detect the incoming audio (another person speaking in the meeting) using a Chrome extension or some JavaScript?